# How to re-route save folder destination

Tags: prison-architect

I have a flash drive where I keep all of my game save backups, and it would be nice to have it automatically save there. Is there a way that I can re-route the save folder destination to my flash drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Linux:

Use the `ln` command to make a symbolic link that replaces the original save directory with a link to the save directory on your flash drive (assumed to be mounted at `/mnt/flashdrive`).

```
ln -s ~/.Prison\ Architect/saves /mnt/flashdrive/saves
```

### Windows:

Use the `mklink` command in an *elevated* command prompt to create a junction from the original save directory to your flash drive (assumed to be `F:`).

```
mklink /j F:\saves C:\Users\YOUR_NAME\AppData\Local\Introversion\Prison Architect\saves\
```

Comment: I use the Windows `cmd.exe` for this, right?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to run it as administrator in order to use the mklink command. Right-click the *Command Prompt* icon in Start>Programs>Accessories and select the *Run as administrator* option.